# Dynamics CRM Linq Query Join On This, That, or Other

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm

**What I am trying to do**

I have two entities

*Entity1*

```
Name: MyEntity
Attribute1: Entity2 Reference
Attribute2: Entity2 Reference
Attribute3: Entity2 Reference
```

*Entity 2*

```
Name: My Other Entity
```

Entity 1's Attribute1, Attribute2 and Attribute3 are optional so they also may be null.

I need a linq query that will return Entity 2 records from Entity 1's Attribute1, Attribute2 and Attribute3.
I do not want the references to them as that will mean I have to do another database lookup.

**Example**

```
var rows = (from ent1 in crmLinqContext.Entity1Set
            from ent2 in crmLinqContext.Entity2Set
            where ent1.attribute1 == ent2.Id ||
                  ent1.attribute2 == ent2.Id ||
                  ent1.attribute3 == ent2.Id
                  select new entity2 
                  {
                     Id = ent2.Id,
                     Name = ent2.Name
                  });
```

**Problem**

I am getting the error "A 'SelectMany' operation must be preceeded by a 'Where' operation that filters 
by an entity ID."

**Question**

How do I join using XrmContext from all three possible attributes

**Update 1**

```
var rows = (from ent1 in crmLinqContext.Entity1Set
                     join ent2_1 in crmLinqContext.Entity2Set 
                     on ent1.attribute1.Id equals ent2_1.Id into et1
                     join ent2_2 in crmLinqContext.Entity2Set
                     on ent1.attribute2.Id equals ent2_2.Id into et2
                     join ent2_3 in crmLinqContext.Entity2Set
                     on ent1.attribute3.Id equals ent2_3.Id into et3
                     from result1 in et1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     from result2 in et2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     from result3 in et3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new 
                     {
                         Results = new List<Entity2>()
                         {
                             result1,
                             result2,
                             result3
                         }
                     });
```

This gives me the error
The 'GroupJoin' operation must be followed by a 'SelectMany' operation where the collection selector is invoking the 'DefaultIfEmpty' method.

Comment: Looks like you missed a linking table in your design.  That, in part, is what is making your query so difficult.

Comment: Thought experiment: what happens if your parent has four children?

Comment: Maybe parent, child entity names were not clear enough. Updated example to remove confusion. Its not really a parent child relationship

Comment: Will your entities ever have more than 3 self-relationships?

Comment: They are not self relationships. ent2 relates to ent1 3 times

Comment: Always exactly three times?  Maybe you'd better tell us what the actual use case is.

Comment: I have updated the question. Lets for argument sake the Entity 1 table only has 3 fields in the database. All fields are pointing to to a record in the Entity 2 table. I want to get all 3 Entity 2 records. There are only ever 3 fields containing 3 references to Entity 2 records.